# Auto completion not working for Objective-C function that bridge to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have imported some Objective-C files in my Swift framework by using umbrella header. Here when I type the objective-c function in swift code it's not showing the suggestion and also text colour for that function is always in white colour (in dark theme Xcode) when I complete type that function (Build get success with that function). Is there any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: You probably have circular bridging header imports - you need to debug using the steps described [here](https://miqu.me/blog/2017/06/16/fixing-autocompletion-on-mixed-objective-c-and-swift-projects/).

Comment: @pranav I have checked from that link, there is no circular bridging imports.

Comment: Sometimes these kind of problems can be fixed by closing xCode, deleting the Derived Data folder and opening xCode again.